# Can I access ADLS from Azure Databricks using an ADF managed identity?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a ADF which has a managed identity able to access the ADLS. Now I need this ADF to call a Databricks notebook and this notebook should access the ADLS as well. Can I do it using the managed identity from ADF? How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now the [Azure Active Directory credentials passthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/credential-passthrough/adls-passthrough) doesn't work with service principals & managed identity.  You can use managed identity to connect to the Databricks workspace itself (see [docs](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/azure-databricks-activities-now-support-managed-identity/ba-p/1922818)), but from the workspace you need to setup something to access data on ADLS.  You have two possibilities:

- [mount the ADLS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#---mount-adls-gen2-storage) into Databricks workspace using the service principal
- [setup necessary Spark properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/adls-gen2/azure-datalake-gen2-sp-access#access-adls-gen2-directly) to connect to ADLS directly using the service principal

Comment: Do you mean I need an additional service principal for the mount or could I use the SP from the MSI? It seems to me I cannot mount an adls container via an MSI or am I missing something?

Comment: You need Service Principal